# How to force Chrome's script debugger to reload javascript?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I really like the ability to edit javascript in the chrome debugger however, I find that it can be really problematic getting the debugger to re-fetch the JavaScript from the server.

Sometimes I have to go as far just closing the debugger and reloading the frame works OK - but other times (an dI cannot pin down under what conditions this occurs) I have to clear my temporary internet cache.  Sometimes I swear I have to close chrome completely, then clear the cache and then load the page before the debugger finally shows me the most up-to-date script.

(NB.  There is no caching of the script by the web server)

I was wondering if anyone knew of a quick and easy way to tell the debugger to invalidate all its javascript and fetch it all anew on page reload?

Comment: Sometimes I even have to restart IIS Express to get things to reload properly.

Comment: I am having such trouble with this today that I've tried all the suggesstions here and filed a bug.  I am totally dumbfounded at this point why I can no longer set breakpoints in my files.  I can only set them in the page views and not the workspace views.

Answer (score 355, accepted):

While you are developing your script, try disabling the Chrome cache.

When you reload the page, the JavaScript should now get refreshed.

---

## Chrome circa 2011

[image: Open settings]
[image: Disable the cache]

---

## Chrome circa 2018

[image: Open settings]
[image: Disable the cache]

You can also access it on the network tab:

[image: Network tab]

Comment: So, does this apply all the time, or only when the debugger is open?

Comment: only when the Dev Tools are open

Comment: I've had that set all along, and now all of a sudden, I'm stuck with a certain file. Anyone find a solution?

Comment: @IronicMuffin See my answer to force refresh a specific resource

Comment: This just added some years to my life. I tried the CMD+SHIFT+R but that didn't do it. Thanks

Comment: Indeed, like @Karolis commented: [Chrome DevTools' Disable Cache invalidates the disk cache (great for developing!), but.. only while devtools is visible](https://twitter.com/ChromiumDev/status/227356682890670080).

Comment: Incase images are blocked for you this is how to disable the cache http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development

Comment: I'm assuming this disables *all* cache. It'd be nice to have a `Disable JavaScript cache` option!

Comment: For those who are coming to this question more recently, note that the settings menu is off the three vertical dots menu in Developer Tools.  There you will be able to check the box to disable cache.

Comment: In order to find this I had to scroll down about a page past 3 other groups to Network, then Disable Cache is the third option down.

Comment: But why on Earth this is not the default? I mean who wants to use cache while developing?

Comment: I disable the Cache through Network Tab and my JS started reloading, really thanks adrianbanks

Comment: True story: 
"9 years later, he came upon the stack overflow article he never knew he was searching for the entire time. After carrying the heavy weight of frustration for so long, the realization he was now in a state of complete contentment nearly lifted him out of his chair. He breathed a new breath, the first of his new life. And he went on." 
Thank you @adrianbanks for the inspiration.

Comment: when working with js make sure its not cache by server too , wordpress devs be careful sometime server have cache js file while you struggling with browser and abusing google lol

Answer (score 146):

[image]

The context menu shown above is accessible by **right clicking / presssing & holding** the "reload" button, while **Chrome Dev Tools is opened**.

Empty cache and hard reload works best for me.

**Another Advantage:** This option keeps all other opened tabs and website data untouched. It only reloads and clears the current page.

Comment: That one is usefull especially because it is simple to explain. I was under the problem with a client not seeing the modification made on his website. Press F12, then right click on the reload button, choose Empty Cache and Hard Reload. I was done, thans to that comment :-)

Comment: Its's the best chrome feature :) , anytime mate.

Comment: Thanks!  I was trying to figure out why the Reload button sometimes gave me a menu and sometimes didn't.

Comment: I had no problems with Ctrl+Shift+R when reloading Javascript files, but this would not bring back updated content that was served in HTML files. Empty Cache and Hard Reload did the trick for that.

Comment: Best way to do it, use this empty cache and hard reload

Comment: Wow! Who would have known, all these years and there was this option all along. (Sorry for the pointless comment, but I had to).

Answer (score 40):

You can always clear a specific file by doing the following:

1. Open Dev Tools
2. Click on the Sources tab
3. Find your script / image / file
4. Check the right panel to see if your file is up to date

If not:

1. Right click the resource in the left panel and choose 'Open Link in New Tab'
2. Force a reload of the resource with the methods above. (See @Bishoy Hanna's example)

This is very handy if you have resources that are in frames and `CTRL+F5` is not force refreshing them.

Comment: true. pressing CTRL + F5 = Clear cache refresh current page

Comment: I don't have a Resources tab.

Comment: @MikeW it's been renamed to Sources -- I've updated the answer

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> quickly clears the cache.

Comment: ctrl-f5 does not cut the mustard I am afraid.  The old javascript file remains in the debugger.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a shortcut to DevTools:

1. <kbd>F12</kbd> to open Chrome DevTools
2. <kbd>F1</kbd> to open DevTools Settings
3. Check *Disable cache (while DevTools is open)* as shown below:

[image]

Note: Updated per Dimi's comment. They tend to move it so let me know or update the post if you notice that it's changed.

Answer (score 9):

For Google chrome it is not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. It's <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to clear the current cache! It works for me !

Comment: Why ? I don't understand what is the difference between that and a comment. At the end, the most usefull question will be see at the top of the post.

Comment: The questioner did not mention at any point *Ctrl-F5*, so by definition your answer is not an answer to the question asked by the questioner, its rather a *comment*, a correction to the other peoples answers and it should be treated as so.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> would force reload the script in chrome.

Answer (score 2):

If you are making local changes to a javascript in the Developer Tools, you need to make sure that you turn OFF those changes before reloading the page.

In the Sources tab, with your script open, right-click in your script and click the "Local Modifications" option from the context menu. That brings up the list of scripts you've saved modifications to. If you see it in that window, Developer Tools will always keep your local copy rather than refreshing it from the server. Click the "revert" button, then refresh again, and you should get the fresh copy.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as the Chrome debugger loads source files into memory and wont let them go despite of browser cache updates, i.e. it has its own cache apart from the browser cache that is not in sync. At least, this is the case when working with source mapped files (I am debugging typescript sources). After successfully refreshing browser cache and validating that by browsing directly to the source file, you download the updated file, but as soon as you reopen the file in the debugger it will keep returning the old file no matter the version from the ordinary browser cache. Very anoying indeed.

I would consider this a bug in chrome. I use version Version 46.0.2490.71 m.

The only thing that helps, is restarting chrome (close down all chrome browsers).

Answer (score 1):

[image: Chrome]

**Right click on reload button in chrome and click "Empty Cache and Hard Reload"**

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this Chrome extension to quickly switch between using or not the cache: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/classic-cache-killer/kkmknnnjliniefekpicbaaobdnjjikfp

Comment: Link is dead but the "Classic Cache Killer" Chrome extension works well ... https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/classic-cache-killer/kkmknnnjliniefekpicbaaobdnjjikfp

Comment: Nowadays you can just "disable cache" in the dev tools "network" tab (see accepted answer)

Comment: true but the Chrome extension does not require devtools to be open

Answer (score 0):

If the files which you are loading are cached and if the changes you have made does not reflect in the code then there are 2 ways you can deal with this

1. Clear the Cache as everyone told
2. If u want Cache and only the files have to be reloaded , you can go to network tab of the dev tool and clear whatever was loaded. next time it will not load it from cache. you will have your latest changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are also 2 (quick) workarounds:

1. Use incognito mode wile debugging, close the window and reopen it.
2. Delete your browsing history

Answer (score 0):

Deactivating Breakpoints caused the new script to load for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's easiest to work in a 'private browsing session' of chrome, to ensure that your javascript files don't come from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

If there is document on URL:
file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/site/index.html

Add any parameter to your URL, like this:
file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/site/index.html?foo=777

and the browser'll refresh all sites resources