# Changes in Javascript have no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

--UPDATE--
Turns out my browser is caching my scripts. I can't believe I couldn't find this out from 15 mins of Googling..

I've hit upon something I think is really weird. Turns out, it doesn't even matter what I write into the script! I'm using CodeIgniter

This is in my view:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/js/ajax.js');?>"></script> 
<span id="dislike_error" style="color:red;"></span>
```

`ajax.js` is currently empty but this is the code before:

```
$('#btn_dislike').click(function (){

    $.post("interact/"+challenge_id, {'action':'dislike'}, function(data){
        if (data == true){
            var old_likes_number=parseInt($('#dislike_number').text());
            var new_likes = old_likes_number+1;
            $('#dislike_number').text(""+new_likes);
        }
        else{
            $('#dislike_error').text('WTFF');
            //$('#dislike_error').html("You have already disliked this challenge.").


        }

    }).fail(function(){alert('Fail');});
});
```

Why is this? I tried closing the tab in the browser. I tried restarting the browser. But somehow the browser remembers the Javascript that was there before?!

Comment: Sounds like the browser cached the file and isn't bothering to check with the server to see if it's been modified. Just hit Ctrl+F5 and that should fix it.

Comment: GET requests are cached. Caching 101. That is what makes the web faster.

Comment: press ctrl+shift+delete and delete cache

Comment: press ctrl + f5 .. :):)

Comment: Chrome seems to be some kind of buggy. I sometimes have to hit CTRL+F5 several times before it actually reloads my scripte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your browser is caching your script. Auto-reload the the cached things in development time.

- [Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7100501/887149)
- [Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/289771/887149)
- [IE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2755811/887149)

Answer (score 1):

Clear your cache in your browser

Or.. The best way would be to add this

```
# don't cache css or js, for debugging, only
<filesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access"
  Header append Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>
```

to your .htaccess file, to force the browser to update css and js files everytime, you'd only want this on a development machine, though.

Comment: You're better off telling your browser not to cache it, no risk of leaving it in there by accident