# When coding HTML, browser doesn't always detect changes

Tags: php, html, css, browser-cache

When I'm coding HTML and CSS and load the page in the browser to check changes, sometimes it doesn't update for a while. This obviously causes problems with incremental changes where it's hard to tell if it's changed to suit my latest change or not.

I was wondering if there was a way around this? Possibly a browser (or mode) which is especially for this situation that doesn't have this behaviour?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078953/how-to-force-chromes-script-debugger-to-reload-javascript

Comment: Disable your browser cache...

Comment: use incognito browsing or private browsing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on OSX, this will avoid your browser reading its cache when loading the page (at least when it's Chrome or Firefox)

Comment: On Chrome you can also install this cool extension I use: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap

Comment: Hmm, this isn't working. Perhaps it's something to do with it being a .php file on localhost. Surely it should still refresh right away?

Comment: Depends what's in your .php ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could try deleting your browser cache and reloading the page.
In case of CSS I also found sometimes I will need to load the CSS file separately in my browser and refresh it to update.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your browser cache, you can test this by clearing it or doing a "hard refresh" to confirm.

You will need to throw some no cache headers if you want to stop this permanently, you can do this from the web server or server-side code depending on your setup (see [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers))

Answer (score 1):

On windows refresh with `CTRL + F5`. The browser will not show from cache. Also in developer tools you can tell it not load from cache

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly because of browser cache.

Just a suggestion(You may find it useful, As an addition to other answers):

If you are on chrome then there is an option to disable cache while the dev toolbar is open. It works for me to ensure there is no caching while I am developing. (I keep my dev toolbar open all the time while developing so it works for me), Here is the screen shot.

Quote from chrome dev tools (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/settings)

> General
>
> Disable cache Will prevent the caching of resources ONLY for pages
>   which have DevTools open. This will not disable caching if the
>   DevTools are closed

.

[image]

Comment: Ah, i followed these steps, but it still isn't updating my content. It's possibly because I'm saving to localhost. Maybe that has some effect?

Comment: Interesting, Try sending `no-cache` header from your web server and then check to make sure if it is the cache issue or something else.

Comment: @Andrew you are right,`no-cache` header will prevent browser from caching the result. BTW! It is not a good idea to set these headers for static resources like js/css/images etc. Caching static assets is good idea. I belive answer above helps you to by pass the cache without `no-cache` header.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm could be a web server setting, caching request to your same resource.  I used to see that a lot on tomcat with JSP.  With tomcat we used to delete compiled classes ('work' folder), though, in your case with PHP you may check your server cache settings (files/sessions).

Example: "A typical web server, such as Apache, uses the time of file modification to inform a web browser of a requested page’s age, allowing the browser to take appropriate caching action. With dynamic web pages, the actual PHP script may change only occasionally; meanwhile, the content it displays, which is often fetched from a database, will change frequently."

Source : http://www.sitepoint.com/caching-php-performance/

Another workaround would be to touch (add a space and save) your PHP file when you want it to reload.